# How To Code A Dropdown Menu Within A Dropdown Menu Option?

Tags: html, css

I'm re-launching [my blog](http://www.blankesque.com) and would ideally like to make changes to the navigations of the blog.

I already have a hovering navigation bar with three tabs and two of these tabs have dropdown options. The 'Blankesque' tab - situated in the left corner of the screen - is such a tab. I would like to add another dropdown menu within this dropdown menu.

This is the current coding which displays the dropdown options in the 'Blankesque' tab:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Blankesque</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/disclaimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This is the basic dropdown menu that appears when you click or the mouse hovers over the tab name 'Blankesque'. I however would like there to be another dropdown menu option titled 'Social' which would then have its own dropdown menu with my relevant social media account links. I have tried the following coding nonetheless it doesn't work well even though I use similar principles.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Blankesque</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a></li>
            <li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/disclaimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Social</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/blankesque'>Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque'>Instagram</li></a>
                    <li><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</li></a>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div style="float:right; margin-top:-4px; margin-right:350px" id="primary_nav_wrap">
<ul style=" border:1px solid #FEB405">
  <li style="background:#ffce00;"><a href="#">Select Dropdown<img width="9" height="5" align="absmiddle" alt="" style="margin-left:10px;" src="images/arrow_down.png"></a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#1">Option 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#1">Option 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#1">Option 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#1">Option 4</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
<style>
    #primary_nav_wrap {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul {
        background: #fcfcfc none repeat scroll 0 0;
        border: 1px solid #e7e7e7;
        float: right;
        list-style: outside none none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul a {
        color: #333;
        display: block;
        font-family: "HelveticaNeue","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: 700;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li {
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li.current-menu-item {
        background: #ddd none repeat scroll 0 0;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover {
        background: #f6f6f6 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul {
        background: #fcfcfc none repeat scroll 0 0;
        display: none;
        left: -178px;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        text-align: left;
        top: 100%;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul li {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #f3f3f3;
        float: none;
        font-weight: normal;
        width: 340px;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul a {
        color: #666;
        font-weight: normal;
        line-height: 120%;
        padding: 10px 15px;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul ul ul {
        left: 100%;
        top: 0;
    }
    #primary_nav_wrap ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a class at your main ul (i added 'main-menu' for example) and then add this css:

```
.main-menu > li > ul,
.main-menu > li > ul > li > ul,
.main-menu > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}

.main-menu > li:hover > ul,
.main-menu > li > ul > li:hover > ul,
.main-menu > li > ul > li > ul > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
}
```