# How to code an additional dropdown menu option within an already existing dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I'm currently re- launching my blog - www.blankesque.com - which is hosted on Blogger and would ideally like to make changes to the navigations of the blog.  I've come to understand that Blogger is limited in its versatility in regards to coding. But I'm hoping to get some help with an issue I've encountered on several occasions other than this one time.

I already have a hovering navigation bar with three tabs and two of these tabs have dropdown options. The 'Blankesque' - situated in the left corner of the screen - is such a tab. I would like to add another dropdown menu option within this dropdown menu.

The current coding I have for the particular tab I've stated about above is as follows:

```
<ul>
<li><a href='#'>Blankesque</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a>      </li>
<li><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/disclaimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>Social</a>
<ul>
<li><a href='http://www.twitter.com/blankesque'>Twitter</a></li>
<li><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque'>Instagram</li></a>
<li><a href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</li></a>
```

I have tried to code the appearance I'm looking for however as from the coding above you can see that the additional dropdown menu options of the 'Social' tab appear continuous like the other options. Ideally I would like the Twitter, Pinterest, Instagram and Bloglovin links to only appear when the mouse hovers over or the mouse clicks the word 'Social'.

In its simplest form I want to have a dropdown menu option within an already existing dropdown menu option.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Iram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To Code A Dropdown Menu Within A Dropdown Menu Option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023654/how-to-code-a-dropdown-menu-within-a-dropdown-menu-option)

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more on [Bootstrap demo page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-example). On this site there are examples of dropdown menus. Copy the example provided, enter in Developer tools (F12) and inspect the element that you want to change (You can right click on it and hit **Inspect element**). Replace the content of the selected **li** with the code that you copied.

This should help you find a solution to the problem, if you don't mind using the BOOTSTRAP.

Answer (score 0):

This is your absolute solution if you take simple HTML-CSS approach:

```
<!--  ****dropdown container****  -->
    <div>
        <select id="myDropDown">
                <option><a href='#'>Blankesque</a></option>
                <option><a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Home</a></option>
                <option><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/about-blankesque-blog.html'>About</a></option>
                <option><a href='http://www.blankesque.com/p/disclaimer-policy_13.html'>Policies</a></option>
        <!--  ***second level dropdown***  -->
                <optgroup id="social_links" label="Social">
<option class="links"><a href='http://www.twitter.com/blankesque'>Twitter</a>
</option>
<option class="links"><a href='http://www.instagram.com/blankesque'>Instagram</a>
</option>
<option class="links"><a
href='http://www.pinterest.com/blankesque'>Pinterest</a>
</option>
                </optgroup>
                </select>
    </div>
```

now, this is simple and straight. If you want some visual smartness then add exactly this to .css:

```
#social_links>.links
{display: none;}
#social_links:hover>.links
{display: block;}
```

**P.S.** The "Social" text(label) inside the menu is default `italic`. To change it's style use `optgroup[label="Social"]{   }` in .css and put your desired style inside the braces.